# Logging - ini-defined log path not appending date

Tags: java

My application requires logging where the application outputs messages to a file called "profile_admin_ddmmyyyy(where ddmmyyyy is the current date). The path is pulled from the current directory using the following code:

```
FileInputStream propFile = new FileInputStream("config.ini");
config.load(propFile);
path = config.getProperty("path");
```

In my ini, I have the "path" as:

```
path=C:\app27\bin\profile_admin_
```

I need to be able to append the date to the end of this file with the file type of ".log". Can anyone help me achieve this?

I have included the Class I call to for writing the log file:

```
private String path;
private boolean appendToFile = false;

public FunctionLogging(String file_path, boolean append_value)
{
    path = file_path;
    appendToFile = append_value;
}

public void writeToFile(String textLine)
{
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy|HH:mm:ss:ms|");
    String timeStamp = format.format(date);

    try
    {
        FileInputStream propFile = new FileInputStream("config.ini");
        Properties config = new Properties(System.getProperties());
        config.load(propFile);
        path = config.getProperty("path");
        FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, appendToFile);
        PrintWriter printlines = new PrintWriter(write);
        printlines.printf("%s" + "%n"+ timeStamp, textLine);
        printlines.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: So what's the specific difficulty that you're facing? Format the current date as a string and append it to `path`.

Comment: I added what my ini says for path, perhaps that will help. I get the file outputted with the name "profile_admin_"

Comment: Of course you do, because you haven't made any attempt to append the date.

Comment: I'm drawing a blank here =/

Comment: Do you know how to get the current date? Do you know how to format a date as a string? Do you know how to append one string to another?

Comment: I already have the current date as a string but no matter where I attempt to add the date and file extension, the file remains the same.

Comment: Please show the code that opens the log file.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the class that writes the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate SimpleDateFormat instance to format the date in the format that you want to use in your filename ("ddMMyyyy"). Then append its result to the path of the file you're opening:

```
FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path + timestamp + ".log", appendToFile);
```